# WSO2-IS Adding Service Principal

Tags: configuration, wso2, kerberos

I think that I found a bug when you are going to add a service principal.

[This is the service that I'm trying to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ONCy.png)

But when you put the password you always get and error who says:
"Password does not meet system requirements. Must be at least 6 characters long." Even if you put a 10 characters password you will get the same error.

Any ideas?

Thank in advance

Comment: Did you check if the password matches with the password regex mentioned in user-mgt.xml

Comment: The password I'm trying to use is: "barranco", so it should be accepted by the requierements in the user-mgt.xml. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/07/kerberos-authentication-using-wso2-products/ I was able to put the password without any issue. what is the IS version you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to do this with the last version of IS. 5.1.0

Comment: edit: I tryed with the 3.2.3 version and everything it's ok. Could be this a bug of the 5.1.0 version?

Comment: I haven't try out this with 5.1.0. Will try out later and let you know